# SQLiteDatabase error: near "in1": syntax error

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have click First button. This time show error in1

I have put the `=` in the query some error near "=": syntax error

How to solve it?

In this query I have use String Builder for concat to multiple string

```
 public List<People> getPeople(String category_id) {
    List<People> peoples = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(",");
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from people where category_id in " +(category_id + sb + category_id) , null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String peopleName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PEOPLE_NAME));
            String peopleImage = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PEOPLE_IMAGE));

            People people = new People();
            people.setPeopleName(peopleName);
            people.setPeopleImage(peopleImage);

            peoples.add(people);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("DB", e.getMessage());
    }
    return peoples;
}
```

Comment: for a start you will need a space after `in`

Comment: leave a space after `in`: `in " + (category_id`

Comment: leave space after  _in  " +_

Comment: I'm not seeing the purpose of the StringBuilder. It's just a comma

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Syntax must be:

```
"select * from people where category_id in (" + category_id + sb + category_id + ")"
```

The brackets are part of the IN clause.

or simply:

```
"select * from people where category_id in (" + category_id + ", " + category_id + ")"
```

Because the stringbuilder is not secessary.